# How to add the logo hyperlink in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

In my magento store i have put in my logo, that logo contains two links one is my site link, and another one is my external site link, these two link are created in image mapping functions using adobe dreamweaver tool mapping options, 
So how to add the code in my magento store header.phtml page, pls anyone help me